# Using dict mapping instead of multiple if statements

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, mapping

I have a simple function that takes a `weekday` column and converts it into actual names of the days like so:

```
def convert_weekday(day):
    if day==0:
        return 'Mon'
    elif day==1:
        return 'Tue'
    elif day==2:
        return 'Wed'
    elif day==3:
        return 'Thu'
    elif day==4:
        return 'Fri'
    elif day==5:
        return 'Sat'
    elif day==6:
        return 'Sun'
    else:
        return day

df['day_of_week']=df['day_of_week'].apply(convert_weekday)
```

This works fine, but I would like to reduce the run time using dictionary mapping like this:

```
dict_days = {
    0: 'Mon',
    1: 'Tue',
    2: 'Wed',
    3: 'Thu',
    4: 'Fri',
    5: 'Sat',
    6: 'Sun'
}
def map_days(day):
    func = dict_days[day]
    func()

df['day_of_week']=df['day_of_week'].apply(map_days)
```

But this gives me an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What do/don't you understand from that error message, by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map_days` function is wrong. It's trying to invoke (i.e. `()`) a string that's stored in the dictionary

In fact you don't need the function at all, you can just use the `dictionary.get` method.

```
dict_days = {
    0: 'Mon',
    1: 'Tue',
    2: 'Wed',
    3: 'Thu',
    4: 'Fri',
    5: 'Sat',
    6: 'Sun'
}

df['day_of_week']=df['day_of_week'].apply(dict_days.get)
```